# 3 different ways to bind a class name with knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

Why does in knockoutjs exist 3 methods to bind a css class name and what are the differences?

```
   1. <div data-bind="class: name"> // jquery is needed

   2. <div data-bind="attr: { class: name}">

   3. <li data-bind="css: name">
```

Comment: Note: there is no standard binding called `class` so that must be something custom thing. The other two `data-bind="attr: { class: name}"` and `data-bind="css: name"` are the builtin knockout bindings

Comment: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/wiki/Bindings---class

Answer (score 4):

The main difference between attr and css is attr binding is not just for a class binding but for attributes in general. It always creates the new attribute with the value on the element. So, for example, if you have another class on your element, the attr binding with class will overrides it. css binding will create new class attribute just if it does not exist yet. Otherwise, it will append it to existing attribute.

http://jsfiddle.net/dima_k/kN8Nx/

```
<div data-bind="css: myclass" class='always'>
   Test 1
</div>

<div data-bind="attr:{class: myclass}" class='always'>
   Test 2
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

`attr: { class: name}` binds to the entire class *attribute*. So you must know all of the classes applied to the element.

`css: name` only binds one or more named classes. So if I have the HTML:

```
<span class="myclass" data-bind="css: myOtherClass">
```

I could end up with two classes: `myclass` and `myOtherClass`

I'm not sure about your `class: name` syntax. I can't find any documentation on it?

**edit:** I think the `class` binding may be the old Knockout syntax for the `css` binding. I can find a [wiki page](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/wiki/Bindings---class) for it on Github, but no current source code.

Comment: @bastienne Thanks, added this to the post

Comment: Here's the documentation for the `class` binding: https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html